# replication, uuid field as primary key, row based replication

Tags: mysql, primary-key, replication, uuid

I am looking about the best way to implement a multi-sites replication with MySDQL. As I am mainly a MS-SQL user, I feel quite unconfortable with MySQL replication terminology, and the multiple MySQL versions that do not do exactly the same thing the same way.

My objective is, as per SQL terminology, to have a publisher and many subscribers. Suscribers are open to user updates. Changes are replicated with the publisher, which will then distribute these changes to other suscribers.

So my objective is here to determine the correct primary key rule to be used for our tables. As we want exclusively surrogate keys, we have the possibility to use either integer\autoincrement or uuid/uuid_short fields. In order to avoid replication conflicts, the integer\autoincrement does not fits our needs, as it can create replication conflicts when, between two synchronisations, both servers insert a record in the same table. So, according to me, the correct solution to avoid replication\primary key conflicts would be to:

- use uuid or uuid-short fields as primary keys
- have the corresponding uuid values set by the server at INSERT time
- set the replication to RBR (Row Based Replication - sounds equivalent to MS-SQl merge replication) mode, and not SBR (Statement Based Replication - sounds like transactional replication). As I understand it, RBR will insert the calculated uuid value 'as is' in the other servers at replication time, while SBR will recall the uuid() function and generate a new value on each server ... thus causing a major problem!

Will it work?

Comment: If you define primary key as `PRIMARY KEY(id, server_id)` and then set default values for `server_id` column at each of your newly added servers - you avoid the need for UUID and you avoid pk clashes.

Comment: This is a solution, but i'd love not to have composite primary keys. They make JOINS so hard to understand. I am sure there is a way to have it working without going to such a solution. Thanks anyway.

Comment: UUID's add so much overhead and adding just one more `AND` to your JOIN really shouldn't be the criteria that fails the usage of auto_increment as PK. I tried both ways, UUID was my first choice but they are slow, long, create problems for InnoDB and when you want to manually look something up in your db - it's complete gibberish to look at, making it difficult to quickly look something up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are two unrelated issues here:

1.

Choosing a primary key in a way which is probably unique - UUID is an acceptable approach. You can use it with SBR or RBR, provided the client app generates the UUID. If you happen to be calling the mysql function to generate it, then you need to use row-based replication. Row-based replication is generally much better, so the only reason you'd want to use statement-based replication is backwards compatibility with a MySQL <5.1 slave, or legacy application which relies on some of its behaviour.

2.

Secondly, you appear to want to do multi-master replication. IT WILL NOT WORK.

MySQL replication is extremely simplistic - it writes changes to a log, pushes them from one server to another, reading the log as needed.

You can't do multi-master replication, because it will fail. No only does MySQL not actually support it (for arbitrary toplologies), but it also doesn't work.

MySQL replication has no "conflict resolution" algorithm, it will simply stop and break if a conflict is discovered.

Even assuming that your database contains NO UNIQUE INDEXES except primary keys which are allocated by UUIDs, your application can still have rules which make multi-master fail.

Any constraints, invariants or assumptions within your application, probably only work if the database has immediate-consistency. Trying to use multi-master replication breaks this assumption and will cause your application to enter unexpected (i.e. normally impossible) states.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So I understand from your comments that replication with MySQL is only limited to 'read-only' replication, where updates can only be done on one server, then distributed to 'read-only' servers. It sounds to me like a major limitation to the use of this server. How do MySQL users manage with this limitation?

Comment: Typically by only writing to the master; they either asynchronously queue writes (to achieve high availaibility) or tolerate the master being the only place to do writes. In practice this is not a major limitation. Multi-master replication can only work with MySQL in very limited circumstances, not suitable for general-purpose use (e.g. the application has been very specifically designed to tolerate multi-master situations). As I said, there is no replication conflict resolution, so the only solution is to have no replication conflicts, which in practice means write-in-one-place-only.

Comment: Do you have any references or documentation about databases designed for multi-master replication? There are no add-ons available in the market for conflict resolutions?